# Using an alias for Environment.NewLine

Tags: c#

Current best practice is to use Environment.NewLine in your code to, well, start a new line. I would like to be able to use an alias or overloaded operator in my code so that it is more concise.
Instead of this:

```
MessageBox.Show("My first line here" + Environment.NewLine + "My second line here");
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show("My first line here" + NL + "My second line here");
```

How can I easily set this up one time as an IDE setting, or for a whole project/namespace?

An alias or overloaded operator is that comes to mind, but not sure if there is a good way of doing a global alias that is more concise than Environment.NewLine, and I've never done an overloaded operator before, so not familiar with the ins and outs of that.

Comment: Why not just using a string constant, assigning `Environment.NewLine` to it?

Comment: Show me an example. Assuming a WinForms project, can it be set once, then used throughout the project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple shortening method.  Pop this class in one of your utility assemblies:

```
namespace MyCompany
{
    public static class E
    {
        public static readonly string NL = System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

then you can happily use it as such:

```
using MyCompany;

MessageBox.Show("My first line here" + E.NL + "My second line here");
```

Comment: I have accepted this as the closest to what I am looking for. However, there is a lot of valuable input here. Thanks to all who participated.

Answer (score 4):

```
using static System.Environment;
```

Then you can just use it as `NewLine`

Comment: This is the most elegant solution. Documentation is here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static

Answer (score 3):

Might I suggest that you use an extension method instead?

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string NextLine(this string s, string next)
    {
        return s + Environment.NewLine + next;
    }

    public static string NextLine(this string s)
    {
        // just add a new line with no text
        return s + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var lines = "My first line here".NextLine("My second line here.")
    .NextLine("third line").NextLine();
```

Of course, you can call it `NL` if you wish -- might not be clear, though.

Comment: This is a creative solution, though the resulting code isn't as simple/elegant as I would like. Thanks for offering it.

Comment: This is a [method chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/method-chaining/info) or [fluent interface](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/fluent-interface/info) approach.

Answer (score 2):

use `StringBuilder.AppendLine()` in cases with few `Environment.NewLine`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("My first line here");
sb.AppendLine("My second line here");
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a class to provide the value of `Environment.NewLine` as a member, as [Jesse C. Slicer has already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566579/using-an-alias-for-environment-newline/3566894#3566894):

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class Env
    {
        public static readonly string NL = Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

Then write the following `using` directive:

```
using E = MyNamespace.Env;
```

You can add this `using` directive to your default new class template and any other templates you use (new `struct`, new `interface`, etc.).

Here's where the new class template is on my machine, as an example to get you started:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033

Once this is done, you should be able to write `E.NL` in place of `Environment.NewLine` everywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

Alias won't work - you can alias a namespace or a type, but not a property of a type.  So this works:

```
using NL = System.Environment;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = NL.NewLine;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
// returns: The type name 'NewLine' does not 
// exist in the type 'System.Environment' error
using NL = System.Environment.NewLine;
```

Overloaded operator is an interesting idea, but then you'll have to use something other than a `String`.  Usually people create a `struct` which can take a base string value and then overload the operators.  Not worth the pain if all you want to do is replace the `Environment.NewLine`.  You're better off to use a static extension as suggested by others.

Another alternative (if you're dead set on using `NL`) is to descend all the classes in your framework off of a common parent class which can have the following property:

```
public class BaseParentClass
{
  public string NL
  {
    get { return System.Environment.NewLine; }
  }
}
```

Then in the code for all the descendant classes, your code will look simply like:

```
public class ChildOfBaseParent
{
  public void Show_A_Message()
  {
      MessageBox.Show("My first line here" + NL + "My second line here");
  }
}
```

Of course if your classes do not descend off of a common parent, you will have to refactor the code base for this piece of convenience.  You will need to create a parallel System.Windows.Forms.Form parent for winform classes to have this same behavior.

But definitely worth the pain if you have a lot of string concatenations involving NL...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @abatishchev response you can do nice things with the StringBuilder Class.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

builder.Append("List:");

builder.AppendLine();

builder.Append("1. Boat")

builder.Append("2. Car").AppendLine();

builder.Replace("Boat", "Jet");
```